# how to make a slideshow stop

Tags: javascript, html

I got a slideShow in javascript, but I'm having trouble stopping it... could any one suggest what is the best way to stop the slide show. following is the code for html and javascript

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Picture Show</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Insert your content here -->
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Slide Show</h1>
            <a href="javascript:slideShow()">Start</a>
            <a href="javascript:stopShow()">Stop</a>
        </div>
        <div id="slideShow">
            <img name="image" alt="Slide Show" src="pics/0.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript file

```
//javascript code for slideshow

//pictures
var imgs = [ "pics\/0.jpg", "pics\/1.jpg", "pics\/2.jpg", "pics\/3.jpg", "pics\/4.jpg", "pics\/5.jpg" ];
var imgNum = 0;
var imgsLength = imgs.length-1;

//changing images function
function changeImg(n) {    
    imgNum += n;

    //last position of array
    if (imgNum > imgsLength) {
        imgNum = 0;
    }

    //first position of array
    if (imgNum < 0) {
        imgNum = imgsLength;
    }

    //console.log(images.tagName);
    document.image.src = imgs[imgNum];

    return false;
}

//slideshow function
function slideShow() {
    //slideshow function
    setInterval("changeImg(1)", 2000);
}

//stopping slideshow function
function stopShow() {
    console.log(imgs[imgNum]);
    document.image.src = imgs[imgNum];
}

//window.addEventListener('load', slideShow);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this function with yours, may this will work.

```
//make the myVar variable global so all functions can reach it.
var myVar = null;

//slideshow function
function slideShow() {
    //slideshow function
    //use the globally defined myVar variable to bind to the interval.
    myVar = setInterval("changeImg(1)", 2000);
}

//stopping slideshow function
function stopShow() {
    clearInterval(myVar);  // This clears the interval
    console.log(imgs[imgNum]);
    document.image.src = imgs[imgNum];
}
```

Comment: that clearInterval shouldn't work as it's trying to reach `var myVar` outside the function scope, unless you make the `myVar` variable global and define it outside the function first and remove the `var` inside the function